# Programmers.SE Theme partially covers rev/copyright notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

An *extremely* minor complaint/observation.

The rev notice is partially obscured by the theme. I checked and no other SE sites seem to use images in that part of the footer so the "problem" is isolated to Programmers.SE.

[image: Rev Notice]

Comment: we're tweaking how the footer site links should be arranged in the coming week. I preemptively changed the css on dev, causing the graphic to be on the right. This will be solved once the new footer is on live.

Comment: @Jin - Great. :-)

Comment: @Anonymous The new footer is live, so this is now fixed. Good catch.

Comment: @YannisRizos/Jin - Good job, liking the new footer. More organized. =)